# What does a single @ do?

Tags: syntax

I have a simple expression:

```
N@Log2@g[2048]
```

I understand that [N is Numerical value](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) , that a function called g is being ran with 2048 as its first argument. But **what does a single @ symbol mean?** [The docs don't seem to have an entry for a single @](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html) [The 'Prefix' page does not describe using '@' in an expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html).

Comment: See here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/12  `f@x` is just another way to write `f[x]`.

Comment: Regarding the documentation: open the documentation browser and search for `@`.  It'll lead you to the page on Prefix, which, while certainly imperfect, gives pretty good hints about what this means and where to look for more info ...  Generally the idea is that `f@g@h[x]` is much more readable than `f[g[h[x]]]`.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs. I did actually open http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html, read it, and didn't think it applied here, as it is described as an operator called 'Prefix' and not '@'.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's confusing.